# how can I build packages in launchpad using valac-0.18 or higher?

Tags: shared-libraries, vala, deb, launchpad, pbuilder

How can I build my package using valac-0.18 and libgranite1 on launchpad? It only has valac-0.16 and libgranite0.

I succesfully built a .deb package with pbuilder by adding my computer sourcelist with  "--aptconfdir /etc/apt":

> pbuilder-dist precise create --extrapackages valac-0.16 --extrapackages libgranite-dev --aptconfdir /etc/apt

(I know there is only valac16(and libgranite0) but with apconfdir it made it to 0.23(and libgranite1))

uploaded it on launchpad with

> dput

but launchpad still searches for the old libs.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `vala-team` PPA as a dependency of your PPA to get newer versions of Vala. I'm not sure why you are specifying `--extrapackages` instead of putting these in your `debian/control` file.

Comment: how? I added ppa:vala-team/ppa and elementary-os/stable (valac and libgranite-dev was already there but without --extrapackages I could not add libgranite0 neither in pbuilder) anyway this is my build log  in launchpad right now:
[buildlog](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/163949263/buildlog.txt.gz). 
[/debian/control](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~s-levente89/+junk/resize/files/head:/debian/)

Comment: okay I found how to add ppa dependency, I'll try it. 9min to build. thank you!